# Column text positions don't match; extending column lines?

Tags: css

Day 2 of learning CSS.
The first column isn't vertically aligned like the other two, I changed one of the other two columns with the first column and it seems that any first column is not aligned at the top. [Image of Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSrWn.jpg). It seem like the rest of the CSS that I haven't posted isn't interfering with the columns so why and how to fix this?
The lines in between the columns aren't reaching the top since I added some padding. How can I extend them?

```
/*CSS*/
.types h3 {
    text-decoration: underline;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
}

.types{
    column-count: 3;
    column-rule: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

## EDIT#

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
    <head>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="interview.css">  
        <title>Interviews</title>  
    </head>  
<body>  
    <div class="container">
    /*Content that is above the Columns*/
        <div class="types">
            <h3>Standardised Interview</h3>
            <p>
                /*First Long Paragraph from image*/
            </p>
            <h3>Exploratory Interviews</h3>
            <p>
                /*Second Long Paragraph from image*/
            </p>
            <h3>Unstructured Interviews</h3>
            <p>
                /*Third Long Paragraph from image*/
            </p>
        </div>
        /*More content below the Columns*/
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The headings have default margins which need to be zeroed out.

A [**CSS reset**](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) would be in order but a quick and simple one is:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.types h3 {
  text-decoration: underline;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.types {
  column-count: 3;
  column-rule: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="types">
    <h3>Standardised Interview</h3>
    <p>
      /*First Long Paragraph from image*/
    </p>
    <h3>Exploratory Interviews</h3>
    <p>
      /*Second Long Paragraph from image*/
    </p>
    <h3>Unstructured Interviews</h3>
    <p>
      /*Third Long Paragraph from image*/
    </p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using flex-box to do this.

```css
.types h3 {
    text-decoration: underline;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
}

.types{
  display:flex;  
  align-items:flex-start;
}

.types div {
  border:2px solid red;
  margin:20px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<body>  
    <div class="container">
    /*Content that is above the Columns*/
        <div class="types">
            <div><h3>Standardised Interview</h3>
            <p>
                /*First Long Paragraph from image*/
              </p></div>
            <div><h3>Exploratory Interviews</h3>
            <p>
                /*Second Long Paragraph from image*/
              </p></div>
            <div><h3>Unstructured Interviews</h3>
            <p>
                /*Third Long Paragraph from image*/
              </p></div>
        </div>
        /*More content below the Columns*/
    </div>
</body>
```

You can then use flex-direction to put the items into a single column on smaller devices using media queries (this is a mobile-first example, when the viewport is larger than 600px wide it will change to 3 columns):

```css
.types h3 {
  text-decoration: underline;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}

.types {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
}

.types div {
  border: 2px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}

@media all and (min-width:600px) {
  .types {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    /*Content that is above the Columns*/
    <div class="types">
      <div>
        <h3>Standardised Interview</h3>
        <p>
          /*First Long Paragraph from image*/
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>Exploratory Interviews</h3>
        <p>
          /*Second Long Paragraph from image*/
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>Unstructured Interviews</h3>
        <p>
          /*Third Long Paragraph from image*/
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    /*More content below the Columns*/
  </div>
</body>
```